# C++ WinRT UWP Project doesn't starts

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I just updated my Visual Studio to 2019 16.10.02
And My Application no more starts in Debug mode. It works fine in Release mode.

Error on output window :

```
The program '[39268] UITest.exe' has exited with code -1073741511 (0xc0000139) 'Entry Point Not Found'.
Activation of the Windows Store app 'sm.UITest_e9xffkak0zmp0!App' failed with error 'The app didn't start'.
```

No other clue even with All Exception settings on.

Comment: Please open appxmanifest file and check if the app's entry point is correct.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT it looks ok to me

Comment: Yep, but we can't reproduce this problem. please try to clean your app and delete bin and obj folder or update the app's target version then rebuild the app